# Webpack: how to code split and make extendible in the future

Tags: typescript, webpack

Making a game and we know already how to code-split to have vendor libraries and the core engine as bundles, and have levels split out into separate bundles.

Once the game is live, the number of levels will need to change with more releases - ideally without recompiling the core engine bundle. 
How could this case be organised to allow for variable includes?

We could have the level select in the core load a json list of levels and then async require each one?

Developing in Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

> How could this case be organised to allow for variable includes? We could have the level select in the core load a json list of levels and then async require each one?

Different module systems have different code splitting / lazy loading capabilities. TypeScript tries to be agnostic in this area (see lazy loading : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html)

With Webpack you would use `require.ensure` and that is documented in the `ts-loader` readme : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#code-splitting-and-loading-other-resources

Comment: Thanks Bazarat, your book is an incredible resource! I think I get it now. I will update when I can add a working test.